# Adding hyperlink to cell with text using xlwt

Tags: python, excel, xlwt

I want to add a url as a link below the text in a cell in excel so that user can visit the site. I am trying but its not working. Please help

```
base = xlwt.Workbook()
for k,v in MainDict.items():
    base.add_sheet(k)
    xlwt.add_palette_colour("custom_colour", 0x21)
    base.set_colour_RGB(0x21, 251, 228, 228)
    style = xlwt.easyxf('pattern: pattern solid, fore_colour custom_colour;font : bold on')
    style1 = xlwt.easyxf('font : underline single')
    index = MainDict.keys().index(k)
    ws = base.get_sheet(index)
    col=0
    for sk in MainDict[k].keys():
        ws.write(0,col,sk.upper(),style)
        col+=1
        row =1
        for mk in MainDict[k][sk].keys():
            for lk,lv in MainDict[k][sk][mk].items():
                for items in lv:
                    ws.write(row,col-1,(items + str(Formula('HYPERLINK("%s")'%mk))))
                    row+=1
base.save('project2.xls')
```

Comment: What's the issue? could you add the required and getting output?

Answer (score 2):

You need to make the text a part of a `Formula`, `&` would help with concatenation. Example:

```
import xlwt

wb = xlwt.Workbook()
ws = wb.add_sheet('test')

ws.write(0, 0, xlwt.Formula('"test " & HYPERLINK("http://google.com")'))

wb.save('test.xls')
```

Comment: I used for items in lv:
                    ws.write(row,col-1,Formula('"%s " & HYPERLINK("%s")'% (items,lk)))
                    #ws.write(row,col-1,Formula('HYPERLINK("%s")'%mk))
                    row+=1
 Now it says Exception: String longer than 255 characters

Comment: @RaghavShaligram it is an excel `xls` limitation, see https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/python-excel/Vvu50inITNA.

Comment: So do i have any available options to make this work. Xlwt writes the text perfectly otherwise.the %s given causes the error

Comment: Can i highlight just the link in the text

Comment: How could the row be written where "test" is a variable as well?

Comment: @Phillip use string formatting, e.g. `xlwt.Formula('"%s " & HYPERLINK("http://google.com")' % your_variable)`..

Comment: @alecxe I'm getting the same error because I need to replace the google link text with a variable also: xlwt.Formula(' "%s " & HYPERLINK(' + link + ')' % name)

Comment: formula = 'HYPERLINK("{}", "{}")'.format(link, title)
ws.write(0, 0, xlwt.Formula(formula)) would be a method to use a variable for both link and title, where the link is not visible